# convert canvas to Blob in safari 5.x

Tags: canvas, safari, blob

I am using the following plugin for converting `canvas` to a `blob` .

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

Some how it seems not to be working on safari since `new Blob()` throws `message: "'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a function (evaluating 'Blob()')"`

Is there some other way to convert `canvas` to `blob` on safari

Comment: Isn't it `new Blob()` instead of `Blob()`? It is a class but not a function

Comment: corrected I meant `new Blob()`